# ReaderWriterLockSlim extension with Action

Tags: c#, multithreading, lambda, extension-methods

Consider the following extensions:

```
public static class ReaderWriteExt
{
    public static void ExecWriteAction(this ReaderWriterLockSlim rwlock, Action action)
    {
        rwlock.EnterWriteLock();
        try
        {
            action();
        }
        finally
        {
            rwlock.ExitWriteLock();
        }
    }
    public static void ExecUpgradeableReadAction(this ReaderWriterLockSlim rwlock, Action action)
    {
        rwlock.EnterUpgradeableReadLock();
        try
        {
            action();
        }
        finally
        {
            rwlock.ExitUpgradeableReadLock();
        }
    }
}
```

Also consider the following sample usage (stripped of some supporting code):

```
private static ReaderWriterLockSlim _rwlock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();
private static ... _cacheEntries = ....;

public static void RemoveEntry(string name)
{
    WeakReference outValue = null;
    _rwlock.ExecUpgradeableReadAction(() =>
        {                    
            if (_cacheEntries.TryGetValue(name, out outValue))
            {
                if (!outValue.IsAlive)
                {
                    _rwlock.ExecWriteAction(() => _cacheEntries.Remove(name));
                }
            }
        });
}
```

I'm new to C# coding and I was unable to find enough information about these topics that could guide me. To my question: I am considering using this concept in our production code, is it a bad idea?  What can go wrong?

Comment: We don't know what's in ReaderWriterLockSlim class. Also, you have rwlock.EnterUpgradeableReadLock(); two times, when it should be ExitUpgradeableReadLock() the second time.

Comment: @Maxim:  Thanks for the edit note, and ReaderWriterLockSlim was introduced in .NET 3.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That seems fine to me except that the code looks very cumbersome

I would probably implement `IDisposable` as:

```
public class WriteLock : IDisposable
{
   ReaderWriterLockSlim _rwlock;
   public WriteLock(ReaderWriterLockSlim rwlock ) 
   { 
      _rwlock = rwlock;
      _rwlock.EnterWriteLock(); 
   }
   public void Dispose()
   {
      _rwlock.ExitWriteLock(); 
   }
}
```

Usage:

```
 private ReaderWriterLockSlim _rwlock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();

 //...

 using (new WriteLock(_rwlock)) //<-- here the constructor calls EnterWriteLock
 {
      _cacheEntries.Remove(name);

 } //<---here Dispose method gets called automatically which calls ExitWriteLock
```

Similarly, you can implement `UpgradeableReadLock` class implementing `IDisposable` interface.

The idea is that you can create an instance of disposable class in `using` construct which ensures that in the constructor you enter into write lock by calling `EnterWriteLock()` method, and when it goes out of scope,  `Dispose()` method is called automatically (by CLR) which calls `ExitWriteLock()` method.

Note that it will not dispose `ReaderWriterLockSlim` object; it will dispose `WriteLock` object which is just a wrapper. `ReaderWriterLockSlim` will be as such in the user-class.

Comment: Ah okay, I think this leads to more readable code, but are there technical reasons not to use my concept?

Comment: @Jack: That seems fine to me except that the code looks very cumbersome.

Comment: Your code will dispose the ReaderriterLockSlim after usage. The point of this class is synchronize access between two threads, so probably there are at least two threads accessing the variable, and both will try to dispose the object, generating a ObjectDisposedException. I think... :P

Comment: @vtortola: It will not dispose `ReaderWriterLockSlim` object; it will dispose `WriteLock` object which is just a wrapper. `ReaderWriterLockSlim` will be as such in the user-class.

Comment: I am completely in favour of more readable code, and as such I like your concept.  Does the compiler guarantee inline (non deferred) execution of the Dispose() call?

Comment: @Jack: Yes. It's guaranteed to call `Dispose()` at the closing curly bracket, as indicated in my code (as comment).

Answer (score 2):

I am not seeing any reason why that would not work safely. However, I have a suspicion that it will actually be slower than using a plain old `lock`. The reason is because `ReaderWriterLockSlim` has about 2x the overhead as compared to a `lock`.<sup>1</sup> So you would you need the execution of the code in the critical section to consume a sufficient enough number of CPU cycles to overcome this added overhead just to reach the breakeven point. If all you are doing is simply accessing a `Dictionary` (or whatever data structure `_cacheEntries` happens to be) then I doubt RWLS is right for the situation. Reader-writer locks tend to work better in scenarios where the number of readers significantly outnumbers the writers *and* when the guarded section of code is long and drawn out. Obviously you should do your own benchmark tests because mileage will vary considerably depending on a lot of other factors. The degrees of parallelism and the number of cores in the hardware *could* give you more throughput using RWLS even though a simple breakeven point analysis did not favor them initially.

---

<sup>1</sup>Based on my own tests. `ReaderWriterLock` had about 5x the overhead.

Comment: Thanks for your response, and the further feedback beyond the scope of my question.  Your feedback serves to address excellent points that junior programmers should be aware of.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are technical reasons why this is not a good idea. If the Action throws an exception when updating the data, then the data is now in an unknown and very likely corrupt state. Your code unconditionally releases the writer lock, meaning that other threads are now accessing the partially-updated shared state. This is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: Excellent, I was thinking about this problem as well.

Comment: @Jim: I know, that was a long time ago, but anyway I want to ask a question: why this is a recipe for disaster?
Using RWLock manually you should anyway release a lock in finally clause. This means that using RWLock is a recipe for disaster anyway.

Comment: @SergeyTeplyakov: See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/03/06/locks-and-exceptions-do-not-mix.aspx

Comment: @JimMischel: thanks a lot, I now about this post and about that one: http://joeduffyblog.com/2007/01/29/monitorenter-thread-aborts-and-orphaned-locks/

But this is an issue with all locks but not with this specific technique.